# Problems trying to display JSON data in a django-tables2 table

Tags: json, django, django-tables2

I have django-tables2 set up and working well. I have set my table to be able to update checkbox columns directly from the displayed list. However when my displayed table paginates and I update a value it refreshes the entire page thus sending me back to the first page and I then have to click 'next' to get back to where I was.  So I thought it might be a good idea to throw knockout.js into the mix to bind my individual columns to the corresponding data in my postgres database.  According to the blurb this would allow me to simply refresh the item clicked on without having to refresh the entire page.  I read the tutorial for knockout.js and all seems great and exactly what I am looking for.  I've modified my views and written my js file etc and I am almost there.  I have the JSONResponse from my views.py returning the correct number of rows, however, my django-tables2 tables are rendering each record as a header (ie th) in my table instead of the data as a row (ie td).  Feeling like I've fallen at the last hurdle, I was wondering if anyone can shed any light on how I can fix this last bit of the puzzle please.

view.py

```
def mydatalist(request):
    data = []
    user = get_current_user()
    query = Q(user_fkey=user.id)
    query.add(Q(deleted__isnull=True), Q.AND)
    query.add(Q(master=True), Q.AND)
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(query)
    for task in tasks:
        data.append({"code":task.code, "name":task.name, etc}) 
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

my .js file

```
function Task(data) {
    this.code = ko.observable(data.code);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    etc 
}
function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON('http://myweb.org/tasks/mydatalist/', function (data) {
        if(data){
            var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function (item) {           
                return new Task(item);
            });
        } else {
           alert('data empty!'); 
        }
        self.tasks(mappedTasks);          
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

my django-tables2 tables.py file

```
class MasterTable(ColumnShiftTable):    
    code = tables.Column(attrs={'th':{'class':'centered nodec'}})
    name = tables.LinkColumn(attrs={'th':{'class':'centered nodec'}})
    etc

    class Meta:
        model = Task        
        fields = ('code','name', etc)
        template_name = 'django_tables2_column_shifter/bootstrap3.html'
        attrs={'id':'masterlist', 'class': 'table table-noborder', 'data-bind': 'foreach: tasks, visible: task().length > 0'}
        row_attrs={'id': lambda record: record.pk}
```

So basically everything is kind of working except that when rendered, my django-tables2 table is rendering 11 headers and no data rows instead of 1 header and 10 data rows.

If anyone can shed any light I really would appreciate it or alternatively if someone can suggest another way to achieve not having to refresh the entire page each time, that would be great also.